# Trying to create a Javascript\Jquery function for background image for multiple images with one function

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

Problem with repetition and UGLY code

Create a Javascript function which spits out the html and also assign the background image for each div (the images are in serial a total of 200 images) or should i use a programming language for like angular, php.

I also want to create a modal which opens up each image with previous and next button like slideshow

Or should i use a ready-made plugin

I am a Web Designer and haven't dabbled in Javascript or Jquery.

Original HTML

```
                <div class="content__photos__c__img content__photos__c__img__1"></div>

                <div class="content__photos__c__img  content__photos__c__img__2"></div>

                <div class="content__photos__c__img content__photos__c__img__30"></div>
```

SCSS

```
        &__15{
            background-image: url('../img/photos/15.jpg');
        }

        &__16{
            background-image: url('../img/photos/16.jpg');
        }

        &__17{
            background-image: url('../img/photos/17.jpg');
        }
```

Javascript or JQUERY function idea

```
image array = [ ../img/1.jpg,../img/2.jpg,../img/3.jpg . . .. ]

Javascript function

for each image in array{
create a div with class container+"array[i]"  and
assign style background image = url("array[i]")
image ++ until all images are over
}

Open a Javascript modal for each image corresponding to array[i]
Onclick show existing modal change style to display : block
with previous and button iterating on image array.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to automatically generate div tags and set to them a background image

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')

    for(var i=1 ; i <= 200;i++ ){
        var div = document.createElement('div')
        div.style.backgroundImage ='url(../photos/'+i+'.jpg)'
        div.id = 'img'+i;
        div.className = 'img img'+i
        body.appendChild(div);
    }
```

you can also edit the style it as you want